# Configure hadoop.service.shutdown.timeout property

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I need to configure the value of `hadoop.service.shutdown.timeout` due to the shutdown hooks triggering a timeout when our MR jobs stop:

```
2023-08-25 08:44:39,566 [WARN] [Thread-0] [org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager] - ShutdownHook '' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
```

The problem is that the value takes effect only when the value is set in `core-site.xml`. For example, if we add it as a property to the env var YARN_OPTS (`-D hadoop.service.shutdown.timeout`) or set it in the code (an instance of Configuration class which is passed to the `ToolRunner`), even though the value changes(we checked this through logging), the timeout is triggered based on the value from `core-site.xml` or default value if not specified in the file.

Is this property configurable only from the `core-site.xml` config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the short answer is "yes", via `core-site.xml` only, because Hadoop's [`ShutdownHookManager`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.3.0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager.java#L102) creates a new Configuration object by reading `core-site.xml` when shutting down an executor thread.

The long answer is longer but is still "probably yes", unless you find the way to follow a rather obscure advice in the comments to the aforementioned class to register a hook explicitly using `addShutdownHook()`:

```
>  * Unless a hook was registered with a shutdown explicitly set through
>  * {@link #addShutdownHook(Runnable, int, long, TimeUnit)},
>  * the shutdown time allocated to it is set by the configuration option
>  * {@link CommonConfigurationKeysPublic#SERVICE_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT} in
>  * {@code core-site.xml}, with a default value of
>  * {@link CommonConfigurationKeysPublic#SERVICE_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT}
```